# D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG debug flag doesn't work

Tags: c++, debugging, directx, direct3d

Good afternoon. In my project, I created a device with the D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag, but it still does not display error information.
I get error 0x80070057, but the debug flag shows nothing, as if I haven't initialized it.

```
D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, DriverTypes[DriverTypeIndex], nullptr, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, FeatureLevels, NumFeatureLevels,
            D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &pD3DDev, &FeatureLevel, &pCtx);
```

Comment: Check Chuck Walbourn's blog: https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/ but also the official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-layers. If you're running on Windows 10, make sure you installed the 'Graphics Tools' optional feature: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-2015-and-graphics-tools-for-windows-10/ read all these carefully, the solution is probably in one of these links.

Answer (score 0):

According to the document for `D3D11CreateDevice` function, in order to use `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` flag, you must have D3D11*SDKLayers.dll installed. It can be obtained through the Windows SDK.

Comment: sdk I have installed. SDK 10.0.194041.1. Also i have DirectX sdk

Comment: @user14487311 What Windows OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You must have Windows SDK. If you can compile the code, you likely have it.

To view the debug output from the D3D debug runtime, you must run your app with debugger attached.

And not just any debugger. If your app has components written in .NET, visual studio has 2 distinct debuggers, managed and native. Managed debugger doesn’t listen to these `OutputDebugString` events, you must run with native debugger attached. If your startup project is .NET, right click on the startup project, Debug tab, check “Enable native code debugging”.

P.S. I wonder why are using an array for driver types? In almost 100% of cases, the only reasonable value to pass there is `D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE`